# WPF - best control to show chess moves?

Tags: wpf, text, click

What kind of WPF text control would be best to display the moves of a chess game?  Ideally the clicked move would highlight in bold.  Example text below. Each move should be clickable, should highlight when clicked (e.g. Bxf6) and would call some code to action the move.

1. d4 Nf6 2. Bg5 d5 3. **Bxf6** gxf6 4. Nf3 Nc6 5. e3 Bg4 6. Be2 e5 7. c3 Qd7 8.
   Nbd2 O-O-O 9. Qa4 e4 10. Ng1 Bxe2 11. Nxe2 Qg4 12. g3 h5 13. h3 Qf5 14. h4 Kb8

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using ListBox with TextBlock as ListBox.ItemTemplate and WrapPanel as ListBox.ItemsPanel.

You can also highlight the ListBox current selected item.

Comment: Thanks.  In an average game that could mean 80 textboxes  -  is that likely to provide a performance impact if all 80 have to be redisplayed due to a redisplay of the moves, or are TextBlocks pretty quick?

Comment: In my currently working project, we use a listbox with over 300 textboxes inside. The lenght of each textbox is around 200 character. Nothing to worry about performance.